# Raising a matrix to the power method JAVA

Tags: java, math, matrix, multiplication

I am having a really hard time creating a method to raise a matrix to the power. I tried using this

```
public static int powerMethod(int matrix, int power) {
    int temp = matrix ; 

    for (int i = power; i == 1; i--)
        temp = temp * matrix ; 



    return temp ;
```

but the return is WAYYY off. Only the first (1,1) matrix element is on point.

I tried using that method in a main like so

```
// Multiplying matrices
            for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < column; j++) 
                {
                    for (l = 0; l < row; l++)
                    {
                        sum += matrix[i][l] * matrix[l][j] ;
                    }
                    matrix[i][j] = sum ;
                    sum = 0 ;
                }
                }

    // Solving Power of matrix
            for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < column; j++) 
            matrixFinal[power][i][j] = Tools.powerMethod(matrix[i][j], power) ;
            }
```

Where "power", "row", and "column" is an int that the user enters.

Any ideas how I can do this??

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you trying to raise a matrix to a power, e.g. for matrix M, "N = M^p"? Or are you trying to operate on each individual element in the matrix, and just independently raise them to a power?

Comment: basically M*M*M, for m^3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a lot of issues here.

First, your matrix squaring algorithm has a (common) error. You have:

```
for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < column; j++) {
        for (l = 0; l < row; l++) {
            sum += matrix[i][l] * matrix[l][j] ;
        }
        matrix[i][j] = sum ;
        sum = 0 ;
    }
}
```

However, you need to store the result in a temporary second matrix, because when you do `matrix[i][j] = sum`, it replaces the value at that position with the output, then later results end up being incorrect. Also I suggest initializing `sum` to 0 *first*, since it appears you declare it outside of this loop, and initializing it first protects you against any arbitrary value `sum` may have before going into the loop. Furthermore, it is not immediately clear what you mean by `row` and `column` -- make sure you are iterating over the entire matrix. E.g.:

```
int temp[][] = new int[matrix.length];

for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    temp[i] = new int[matrix[i].length];
    for (j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        sum = 0 ;
        for (l = 0; l < matrix.length; l++) {
            sum += matrix[i][l] * matrix[l][j] ;
        }
        temp[i][j] = sum ;
    }
}

// the result is now in 'temp', you could do this if you wanted:
matrix = temp;
```

Note that `matrix.length` and `matrix[i].length` are fairly interchangeable above if the matrix is square (which it must be, in order to be multiplied by itself).

Secondly, your multiplication *squares* a matrix. This means if you repeatedly apply it, you keep squaring the matrix every time, which means you will only be able to compute powers that are themselves powers of two.

Your third issue is your final bit doesn't make much sense:

```
for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < column; j++) 
        matrixFinal[power][i][j] = Tools.powerMethod(matrix[i][j], power) ;
}
```

It's not immediately clear what you are trying to do here. The final part seems to be trying to raise individual elements to a certain power. But this is not the same as raising a matrix to a power.

What you *need* to do is define a proper matrix multiplication method that can multiply two arbitrary matrices, e.g.:

```
int[][] multiplyMatrices (int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    // compute and return a x b, similar to your existing multiplication
    // algorithm, and of course taking into account the comments about
    // the 'temp' output matrix above
}
```

Then computing a power becomes straightforward:

```
int[][] powerMatrix (int[][] a, int p) {
    int[][] result = a;
    for (int n = 1; n < p; ++ n)
        result = multiplyMatrices(result, a);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If I understand your algorithm correctly, you're actually raising each matrix to the power of `n+1`, not to the power of `n`.  Look closely at your `powerMatrix` method.

Comment: Cool.  You have my upvote.  This answer looks like it was hard work.

Comment: Wow looks really good. I'm going to try this now, sorry for the late reply been really busy with my other subjects in school (Physics to be exact lol, its a killer!). @JasonC

Answer (score -4):

Why not just use `Math.pow`?

```
    import java.lang.Math;
```

Then you just have to do

```
    matrixFinal[power][i][j] = (int) Math.pow(matrix[i][j],power); //might have to cast this to an int
```

Comment: because that's not what it means to raise a matrix to a power.

Comment: @David Wallace, his method for raising a "matrix" to a power is actually just raising an int to a power. And that is what I have provided an answer for.